# Google play services Conflict in Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

I am getting this error:

> Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0, but version
>   9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.

It is forcing me to use version 9.0.0, but I want to use 9.4.0.

Suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced this issue and found a solution by simply putting this line at the end of application graddle file instead of top

**`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`**